# WPF MultiLanguage should I read the resources from SERVER(WCF) or client side?

Tags: wpf, wcf

I´m creating a multilanguage application in WPF and WCF....all my business logic are exposed by WCF.

What would by the best way to load my resources, from server or locally?

1. Locally: Loading all resources at the client side locally.
2. Server: Passing alll the resoucers(xaml) throught the network, caching all the resouces locally. Should I loose performance?

All options should be apreciated.

Tks,
William

Answer (score 0):

My opinion would be that the client interacts with the user, so it should be localized, so the resources belong with the client. On the other hand, the service interacts with other software, so it should be culture independent, so it shouldn't need localized resources. So, since the resources somehow naturally belong into the domain of the client, I'd deploy them with the client, too.